# Does Elasticsearch accept 1 or 0 for searching on boolean field?

Tags: elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

this is part of my elasticsearch query:

```
 {
    "match": {
        "value": {
            "query": "1",
        }
    }
}
```

value is a boolean field in my index, does elasticsearch accept 1 as true and 0 as false in search on the boolean field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as specified [in the doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/boolean.html)  ES accept `true/"true"/false/"false"` as boolean values.

Other values like `0/1` will throw error in recent versions

> error: failed to create query: Can't parse boolean value [1](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/boolean.html), expected
> [true] or [false]

NB: you should use a [term](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) query to filter in boolean field

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to test...

First create the index:

```
PUT test 
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "bool_field": {
        "type": "boolean"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then index a document:

```
PUT test/_doc/1
{
  "bool_field": true
}
```

Try to query using 0/1 instead of a boolean

```
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "bool_field": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

Response: `Can't parse boolean value [1], expected [true] or [false]`

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "query_shard_exception",
        "reason" : "failed to create query: Can't parse boolean value [1], expected [true] or [false]",
        "index_uuid" : "bZpN3j1kT9KtMBnGkpOmKQ",
        "index" : "test"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "all shards failed",
    "phase" : "query",
    "grouped" : true,
    "failed_shards" : [
      {
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "test",
        "node" : "CyVrqrOtR0CP3RfZtdBTag",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "query_shard_exception",
          "reason" : "failed to create query: Can't parse boolean value [1], expected [true] or [false]",
          "index_uuid" : "bZpN3j1kT9KtMBnGkpOmKQ",
          "index" : "test",
          "caused_by" : {
            "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason" : "Can't parse boolean value [1], expected [true] or [false]"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

PS: It used to be possible up to [ES 5](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/boolean.html). As of ES 6, only true/false are accepted values for boolean fields.